# How to order by a column greater than 0 then by date

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

Lets say I have a table called Car and with the columns Age and CreationDate.

I now want to order so that all cars that have an age greater than 0 are sorted first and then sorted by creationDate in descending order. So it doesn't matter if the cars age is 4,6,7 for example just that it is greater than 0. This would mean that basically all rows are sorted by CreationDate, except that all the cars with an age greater than 0 are sorted first.

For example the below won't work because the cars would first be sorted by the age and ignore what the actual CreationDate is. (I don't want to reverse it and have CreationDate first either because then the cars with age > 0 wouldn't be listed first).

```
SELECT * FROM Car ORDER BY Age, CreationDate DESC
```

Any help or input is highly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can use a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT *
FROM Car
ORDER BY CASE WHEN Age > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END,
         CreationDesc DESC
;
```

Comment: Thank you, will accept this one since you posted first

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    Car AS C
ORDER BY
    CASE 
        WHEN C.Age > 0 THEN 1 -- All ages above 0 will get a value "1"
        ELSE 999 END  -- The rest will have value "999"
    ASC, -- The order is ascendent, so "1" will go first and "999" second
    C.CreationDate DESC
```

Comment: Thank you, appreciate the comments

Answer (score 0):

Using a `CASE` expression as other answers have suggested, although works, will not query using the `SORT` order of any applicable `INDEX` applied to the column(s). That is not SARGable.  The engine will use a `SORT` operator, which is a blocking operator, and thus bad performing.  See recent PASS video by Itzik Ben-Gan

Splitting the Query like so is better performing, will use a `SEEK` twice on an applicable `INDEX`.

```
WITH cteX
AS(
    SELECT C.Id, C.Age, C.CreationDate,  0 AS 'SortCol'
    FROM Car C
    WHERE Age > 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT C.Id, C.Age, C.CreationDate,  1 AS 'SortCol'
    FROM Car
    WHERE Age <= 0
)
SELECT Id, Age, CreationDate
FROM cteX
ORDER BY SortCol, CreationDate DESC ;
```